# How to normalize PWM signal from RX and TX serial lines

Tags: led, pwm, rs232

First off, I just want to apologize for any part of this question that may not be properly phrased. This is still very new area for me.

I am building an adapter for my Commodore 64 that lets it connect to a RS232 DB9 serial port over its user port. I've already made the connector and it works beautifully.

What I want to do now is get fancy and create LEDs that light up when the adapter is either sending or receiving data. I've followed the schematics used in this picture here, but the LEDs are barely visible due to high flicker when data is coming or going. I assume this is PWM and the LEDs are barely lit because the rx and tx lines on the serial adapter are turning on and off at super high rates (its a 9600 baud adapter).

[image]

I've tried connected a few different sized capacitors at different points in the circuit but I'm still not getting the desired effect, which is to see the LEDs light brightly at times of rx and tx signals going across. Is there a way to "tone down" the pwm so that the LEDs are brighter? One LED is wired to tx and another to rx.

Thanks.

Comment: Try making a 'link active' detector; it is not that difficult.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, how is this abusing the protocol? Im just using a lm358 opamp to "sense" the voltage across the rx and tx and then have it output +5v to the LED.

Peter, can you elaborate more on the basics of a link activator or a schematic I can reference?

Comment: What you are looking for is a "pulse stretcher" circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do now is get fancy and create LEDs that light up when the adapter is either sending or receiving data.

This implies peak detect and slow decay.
9600 baud is 960 char/s and a dwell time may be desirable from 0.1 to 1s by changing  1M to 10M (as shown.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftI6vb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Schematic fixed ( brain-phart)

With 50ohm driver in 74HCxxx @5V and 100nF RC=T=5us attack time.
 Good 'nuf.

It is possible to source 1mA current limited into ultrabright LEDs and load directly on Tx Rx.  The logic level threshold is same as TTL= 1.4V and LED needs at least 3 to 5V with 1k series which works for RS-232 ( but blinks )

Comment: Or perhaps use a '123 although this is a nice solution.

Comment: Do i risk "disturbing" the original rx and tx signals with this solution? This rx and tx signals still need to be clean and able to transmit their data.

Comment: NO.  RS-232 old school was +/-15V but can be as low as +/-3V and since driver is current limited.  It is possible to put a Blue or white LED and clamp the LED with a reverse series diode to protect against exceeding -5V , something the old GaAs Red were tolerant to.  This active design presents a 10M load like  a scope probe and series 10k kicks in outside the chip diode protected supply rail.  Remember this RS232 input threshold is the same as TTL. 1.3~1.5V .. alternatively dual HC123 one shot can be used on Active Hi in with 10k series clamp current limit.

Comment: In mid 70's we used breakout boxes with 1k R series GaAs Red LED for each pin RTS,CTS, Rx Tx  which clamps 1k load for dim but visible indication.

Comment: Sounds good, just to confirm, that "inverse" between r2 and D1 is just another two pins between the Hc04 you have in the example right? Since the HC04 has 6 inverse pins.

Comment: Something looks backwards here. The RS-232 signal sits at a negative voltage when idle. The first inverter's output is high, keeping the capacitor charged and the LED off. But when activity occurrs, the capacitor will discharge slowly, delaying the turn-on of the LED. I doubt that this is the behavior the OP is looking for.

Comment: no doubt, not what I intended. schema fixed